# JavaScript Clears My Input Values

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a simple form at work using HTML and have added JavaScript to the page to allow users to add extra rows to a table.  This table has input type="Text" tags and select tags.  When the user clicks the button to add a row, the JavaScript adds a row, but clears the input and select tags.

My script is

```
var x = x + 1;
function another()
{ 
  x = x + 1;
  y = y + 1;
  var bigTable = document.getElementById("bigTable");  
  bigTable.innerHTML += ("<TR><TD CLASS=\"bigTable2\" ALIGN=\"Center\"><SELECT         
    NAME=\"PO" + x + "\"><OPTION>Select</OPTION><OPTION>1234567890</OPTION></SELECT>
    </TD><TD CLASS=\"bigTable2\" ALIGN=\"Center\"><INPUT TYPE=\"Text\" NAME=\"SKU" + x 
    + "\"></TD><TD CLASS=\"bigTable2\" ALIGN=\"Center\"><INPUT TYPE=\"Text\" 
    NAME=\"modelNum" + x + "\"></TD><TD CLASS=\"bigTable2\" ALIGN=\"Center\"><INPUT 
    TYPE=\"Text\" NAME=\"itemNum" + x + "\"></TD><TD CLASS=\"bigTable2\" 
    ALIGN=\"Center\"><INPUT TYPE=\"Text\" NAME=\"qty" + x + "\" ID=\"qty"+x+"\" 
    onBlur=\"total();\"></TD></TR>");
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is here.  Is the "+=" statement basically resetting my table like an = statement would?

EDIT: I don't know how to get all of the code to appear, but what is displayed is not all of my code.  I have a basic Table and using JavaScript use a += statement to add HTML to it.

EDIT: My table is this:

```
<TABLE ID="bigTable">
  <TR>
    <TH>P.O. #</TH>
    <TH>SKU #</TH>
    <TH>Model #</TH>
    <TH>Item #</TH>
    <TH>Quantity</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD CLASS="bigTable" ALIGN="Center">
    <SELECT NAME="PO1">
      <OPTION>Select</OPTION>
      <OPTION>1234567890</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    </TD>
    <TD CLASS="bigTable2" ALIGN="Center"><INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="SKU1"></TD>
    <TD CLASS="bigTable2" ALIGN="Center"><INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="modelNum1"></TD>
    <TD CLASS="bigTable2" ALIGN="Center"><INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="itemNum1"></TD>
    <TD CLASS="bigTable2" ALIGN="Center"><INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="qty1" ID="qty1" onBlur="total();"></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

My JavaScript Replicates everything between the  tags.  And I use the variable x to update the number in the names for the inputs and dropdowns.  Variable Y is used to increment a calculation function.

Comment: What is the table structure? Could you add it to the post please?

Comment: Even if my += statement is changed to += "<BR>" my <BR> is inserted and my inputs are cleared.

Answer (score 4):

When you edit the `innerHTML` of a HTML element, the entire DOM gets re-parsed. Since the input's values aren't actually stored in the input elements's HTML, they are cleared.

An option would be to use DOM manipulation to add the row:

```
function another(){ 
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;
    var bigTable = document.getElementById("bigTable");  
    vat tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = ("<td class='bigTable2' align='Center'><select name='PO" + x + "'><option>select</option><option>1234567890</option></select></td>"+
        "<td class='bigTable2' align='Center'><input type='Text' name='SKU" + x + "'></td>"+
        "<td class='bigTable2' align='Center'><input type='Text' name='modelNum" + x + "'></td>"+
        "<td class='bigTable2' align='Center'><input type='Text' name='itemNum" + x + "'></td>"+
        "<td class='bigTable2' align='Center'><input type='Text' name='qty" + x + "' ID='qty" + x + "' onBlur='total();'></td>");

    bigTable.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Notice how the string no longer contains a `<tr>` tag.
This codes creates a `tr` element, then adds the rows to it, then adds that whole, (parsed), `tr` to the table.

(I also changed the tags / attributes to lowercase and replaced all `\"` with `'` to make it more readable)

Comment: This works and does not remove the values.  Thanks! I'll tinker around with this some more.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, `x += y` is the same as writing `x = x + y`. What's happening here is that you are overwriting the HTML with what you had plus the new row. This clears your inputs because their values are not stored in the HTML (when you type inside one of the input, it's "value" property is not updated in the actual HTML).

So you are basically overwriting your HTML with what was there initially plus some added nodes.

EDIT: Go for Cerbrus's solution. Much cleaner.

Comment: `insertAfter` requires a DOM element, not a HTML string. `element.appendChild(newTR)` will do just fine.

Comment: Just noticed that. Almost forgot about ```appendChild``` (been using that function for quite a long time).

Comment: I'm pretty sure both `x` and `y` aren't even used to position the row and cells of the newly created row. It's only used in its attributes and has no link with overwriting older rows.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up going with was a dynamic JavaScript code that would create a dynamic array and store values in each column of my current table.  Then the code created a new row and the array was then accessed to repopulate the values.